# MVC Model Data Attributes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

So in my view I can add data-XXX but can I do this in the Model instead of having to add the code to the view? Something like this or another way to do it

```
[data-input-mask('99/99/9999')]
public string SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is not [tag:html5] question. Please, add the correct tag (Java, .NET, etc)

Comment: Fixed sorry, data attributes are html5 which is why I added it.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I came here to help you but I don't know anything about C#. I can help you with javascript or php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most complete solution is to create your custom attribute, as explained in the following post

[http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642477/Input-Masking-in-MVC-using-Data-Annotation][1]